# Should I patch any of vulnerabilities manually?

Tags: updates, patch

There are list of vulnerabilities for Ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/
Should I patch them manually or patches are already in updates ?
I asked because some said here that users should apply some patches:
http://www.itnews.com/article/3033965/use-linux-stop-what-youre-doing-and-apply-this-patch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the log (compressed) by my autoupdate this morning:

```
SYS: Feb 17 09:12:58 pern AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Committing packages: dbus.Array([],
signature=dbus.Signature('s')),
dbus.Array([],
signature=dbus.Signature('s')),
dbus.Array([],
signature=dbus.Signature('s')),
dbus.Array([],
signature=dbus.Signature('s')),
dbus.Array([dbus.String('fonts-opensymbol'),
dbus.String('libc-bin'),
dbus.String('libc-dev-bin'),
dbus.String('libc6'),
dbus.String('libc6-dbg'),
dbus.String('libc6-dev'),
dbus.String('libc6-dev-i386'),
dbus.String('libc6-dev-x32'),
dbus.String('libc6-i386'),
dbus.String('libc6-x32'),
dbus.String('libc6:i386'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-base-core'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-calc'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-common'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-core'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-draw'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-gnome'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-gtk'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-impress'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-math'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-ogltrans'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-pdfimport'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-presentation-minimizer'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-style-tango'),
dbus.String('libreoffice-writer'),
dbus.String('libsmbclient'),
dbus.String('libwbclient0'),
dbus.String('multiarch-support'),
dbus.String('ntp'),
dbus.String('ntpdate'),
dbus.String('python-samba'),
dbus.String('python3-uno'),
dbus.String('samba'),
dbus.String('samba-common'),
dbus.String('samba-common-bin'),
dbus.String('samba-dsdb-modules'),
dbus.String('samba-libs'),
dbus.String('samba-vfs-modules'),
dbus.String('smbclient'),
dbus.String('uno-libs3'),
dbus.String('ure')],
signature=dbus.Signature('s')),
dbus.Array([],
signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
```

and as you can see, plenty of `libc`-related updates. So no, nothing manual needed. Just keep to date with the upgrades (this is the advantage of having a Linux distribution and not a home made system).

The worrying part is about all the devices that really use Linux underneath, but are not supported so well and do not provide source code (your router, your car, your microwave, your home temperature control...).

You have to hope that the manufacturer is responsible enough to push an update (ah!)...